# Etymology of the word "sport"

Tags: english, etymology, proto-indo-european

I wonder what is the etymology of the word *sport*.

Vasmer says that it is from *disport* "amusement", a contraction from Middle English *disporten* from Old French *desporter* "to take away", "to distract from the work".

But Starostin's Starling gives another etymology:

Eng. *sport* < Old Eng. *spyrd*, Goth. *spɔrd-s* "racing" < Proto-Germ. **spurd* < PIE **sperdh-* "run competition"

It gives as cognates Hittite *ispart-*, Avest. *sparǝr-* Old Indic *-spūrdhán*, *spárdhate* "competition"

So who is correct?

Note also that Vasmer connects Russian *spor* "dispute" to Avest *pǝrǝt-* and Old Indic *pŕ̥tanā* "struggle" so that the s- in PIE **sperdh-* could be s-mobile.

Also take into account the root **per-* meaning "first", "in front", "against" and Proto-Slavic *perdъ* "before, in front of" < PIE **per-dʰ-o*.

Comment: And how does Starostin explain the semantic change OE spyrd 'stadium (a measure of distance); course' - ME spo(o)rte 'entertainment; pleasure? What about phonetic changes?

Comment: @Alex B. What was in ME, spoorte or disporten, or both?

Comment: The OED gives Vasmer's etymology and doesn't discuss the alternative.

Comment: sport < spyrd seems iffy. Were *spird, *sperd, and/or *spurd attested forms?

Comment: @Anixx sport(e), sporten, sportyn, etc were first attested in the early/mid 1400's as nouns/verbs. Dysport, desport, disport, etc were first attested in the early 1300's as nouns. As verbs, I think they were first attested in Chaucer, i.e. late 1300's.

Comment: Spardha is indeed competition in Sanskrit and  Spardhate is to compete.

Answer (score 1):

The Oxford Dictionary of English ([sport](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/sport), [disport](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/disport)), the [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=sport&searchmode=none), and the [Grimm Brothers Dictionary of German](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GS36131) all give variants of

< Middle English *disport(en)* < Old French *desporter* < from *des-* 'away' + *porter* 'carry' (from Latin *portare*)